# adding listeners to refs returned from custom hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've set up a very basic custom hook in my React app intended to handle a given input element's `onChange` events.

```
const useInput = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    const handleChange = () => {
        console.log("Input updated");
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const { current: input } = ref;
        // The script will never execute past this point.
        if(!input) return; 

        input.addEventListener("change", handleChange);
        return () => input.removeEventListener("change", handleChange);

    // Ref is stateless, so this won't trigger a re-run.
    }, [ref.current]);

    return { ref };
};

const Input = props => {
    const { ref: inputRef } = useInput();

    return (
        <input {...props} ref={inputRef} />
    );
};
```

The issue with my current implementation is that, by default, the ref will be `null`, and since refs are stateless, it will not re-execute that `useEffect` once the element does become available.

So, what is the best way to go about a case like this? Where I *must* return a ref to attach to the element.

Comment: You can use a [callback ref](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a callback ref instead of a regular ref. By using a callback ref, you can ensure that the ref's callback function will be called whenever the referenced element changes.

Try the following:

```
import React, { useRef, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';

//custom hook to handle input changes
const useInput = () => {
  const handleChange = () => {
    console.log("Input updated");
  };

  //callback ref to attach event listener and handle cleanup
  const attachRef = useCallback((input) => {
    if (!input) return; //if input element is null then do nothing

    input.addEventListener("change", handleChange); //attach event listener
    return () => input.removeEventListener("change", handleChange); //cleanup the event listener
  }, []);

  return { attachRef };
};

//component use the custom hook
const Input = (props) => {
  const { attachRef } = useInput();

  return <input {...props} ref={attachRef} />;
};
```

Comment: This can attach the event listener multiple times. `useCallback` does not support a cleanup function.